# Convert PNG byte array to JPEG byte array

Tags: c#, image-processing, encoding, arrays

I use the following code to convert a BitmapSource to a byte array representing a png:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts BitmapSource to a PNG Bitmap.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source object to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>byte array version of passed in object.</returns>
    public static byte[] ToPngBytes(this BitmapSource source)
    {
        // Write the source to the bitmap using a stream.
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Encode to Png format.
            var enc = new Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(source));
            enc.Save(outStream);

            // Return image bytes.
            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

I'm looking to do the same operation but convert a byte array that's a Jpeg without having to create a BitmapSource first.

Signature should look like this:

```
public static byte[] ToPngBytes(this byte[] jpegBytes)
```

This code works but seems inefficient as I've to use a Writeable Bitmap to do this:

```
    private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap;

    private byte[] GetCompressedImage(byte[] imageData, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat format, int width, int height, int bytesPerPixel = sizeof(Int32))
    {
        // Initialise the color bitmap converter.
        if (colorBitmap == null)
            colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96.0, 96.0, format, null);

        // Write the pixels to the bitmap.
        colorBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), imageData, width * bytesPerPixel, 0);

        // Memory stream used for encoding.
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

            // Add the frame to the encoder.
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(colorBitmap));
            encoder.Save(memoryStream);

            // Get the bytes.
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that would only work if saving to disk but this is during runtime and should be from a byte[] source. Thanks though!

Comment: You can replace your WriteableBitmap by calling static method BitmapSource.Create instead : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616045.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a snippet of code to take a byte array of any format and convert it to a byte array with a JPG format:

```
byte[] jpgImageBytes = null;
using (var origImageStream = new MemoryStream(image))
using (var jpgImageStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var jpgImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(origImageStream);
    jpgImage.Save(jpgImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    jpgImageBytes = jpgImageStream.ToArray();
    jpgImage.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: If you need to adjust the compression level when writing the jpeg take a look at [How to: Set JPEG Compression Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx)

Comment: You could put the jpgImage variable also into a using statement and so remove the `jpgImage.Dispose()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Bit Late for the answer but this should help others. In this solution it doesn't matter which type of image it is(as long as it's an image you can convert it to any type.

```
public static byte[] ConvertImageBytes(byte[] imageBytes, ImageFormat imageFormat)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("empty." + imageFormat, FileMode.Create);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                byteArray = ms.ToArray();
                stream.Close();
                ms.Close();
            }
            return byteArray;
        }
```

Use it like as below

```
ConvertImageBytes(imageBytes, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Its very useful!  Originally when I was looking at this, I was hoping for a solution that didn't need to write to disk.